# Permissions error on Ansible playbook updating WordPress with wp-cli tool

Tags: wordpress, ansible, wp-cli

My hosts file

```ini
ansible_user=ansible
```

Playbook

```yaml
- name: WordPress setup
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: ansible
  become: true
  roles:  
  - wp
```

Role's task

```yaml
- name: Update admin user's password
  command: wp user update admin
           --user_pass="{{ wp_admin_pwd }}"
  args:
      chdir: "/var/www/{{ domain_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: www-data
```

Running this playbook, an error shows up:

> Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user
> (rc: 1, err: chmod: invalid mode: ‘A+user:www-data:rx:allow’
> Try 'chmod --help'

The user I'm using to connect to remote server, named `ansible`, is a user with sudo privileges.
The WordPress installation runs under NGINX www-data user.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This could happen when you do not have the `acl` package installed on the remote node. Is it installed?

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε, installing `acl` package solved the issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the chapter [*Risks of becoming an unprivileged user*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user), when becoming an unprivileged user, Ansible has to rely on some tricks to make the file readable by both the `remote_user` and the `become_user`.

One of the way Ansible can solve this on POSIX systems is by relying on the [`setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) command.

> First, if **setfacl** is installed and available in the remote `PATH`, and the temporary directory on the remote host is mounted with POSIX.1e filesystem ACL support, Ansible will use POSIX ACLs to share the module file with the second unprivileged user.

*<sup>Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user</sup>*

So, one way to resolve this is to install the `acl` package on the remote node, for example on Debian distribution (e.g.: Debian, Ubuntu, ...):

```bash
apt install acl
```

Or via the playbook itself in a `pre_tasks`, e.g.:

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: ansible

  pre_tasks:
    - apt:
        name: acl
      become: true
      become_user: root
   
  roles:  
    - wp
```